# React white page issue after building the app

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router

I have done with my project and i want to put it on the server. I did `npm run build`, put everything inside the build folder to the server, when i go to the app on browser i do not get any error, or warning. Just a white blank page.

I think problem is routing part, but i do not know what to do or how to spot the error.

```
"name": "hermes-project",
"homepage": "./",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"auth0-js": "^9.10.2",
"classnames": "^2.2.6",
"clipboard-polyfill": "^2.8.0",
"contentful": "^7.5.0",
"contentful-management": "^5.7.1",
"marked": "^0.6.2",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-markdown": "^4.0.8",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
"react-scripts": "2.1.8"
```

routing part

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Router history={history} component={App}>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Login auth={auth} {...props} />} />


      <Route path="/brand" render={(props) => (
        !auth.isAuthenticated() ? (
          <Redirect to="/login"/>
        ) : (
          <Brand auth={auth} {...props} />
        )
      )} />


      <Route path="/board" render={(props) => (
        !auth.isAuthenticated() ? (
          <Redirect to="/login"/>
        ) : (
          <Board auth={auth} {...props} />
        )
      )} />


      <Route path="/Profile" render={(props) => (
        !auth.isAuthenticated() ? (
          <Redirect to="/login"/>
        ) : (
          <Profile auth={auth} {...props} />
        )
      )} />

      <Route path="/login" render={(props) => <Login auth={auth} {...props} />} />
      <Route path="/callback" render={(props) => {
        handleAuthentication(props);
        return <Callback {...props} /> 
      }}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: so, your app works in development correctly and does not work in production? where do you deploy the app? are you sure it is the correct way to copy paste the build folder? what browser are you using?  what causes you to think that the problem is from routing part? is there any issue with routing in dev environment?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: I just asked those question to clarify that there can be thousands of reasons, I recommend to narrow down your question to a specific problem

Comment: working on it now